# Constraint forcing maximum parameter value to constant

Tags: optimization, constraints, constraint-programming

I have an optimisation problem that I thought should be in the form,
\begin{align}
    \mathrm{maximise}_{x\in\mathbb{R}^p} & f(x) + \lambda\|x\|_1 \\
    \mathrm{subject~to~~~~~~~}                  & x_i \in [0,1], \forall i,\\
                                                & \mathrm{max}_i x_i = 1.
\end{align}
The properties of $f$ may matter later on, but my main interest right now is in the second constraint. It is a convex constraint, and the projection onto the feasible set should be (unless I missed something) just to set the maximum value to 1.

This is, however, not really what I want to do. I would prefer to "spread" the values of $x$ throughout the interval $[0, 1]$, and so *would like* the projection to be
$$
    \mathrm{proj}(x) = x / \mathrm{max}_i x_i, \tag{1}
$$
or something similar.

So the problem is then that I don't recognise this "projection" in (1), and thus don't know what constraint function it would correspond to, nor if I could use that at all. So my question is if anyone has seen something like that before, or has any ideas what to do?

Comment: The set defined by $x_i\in[0,1], \max_ix_i=1$ is actually not convex - it is the unit sphere in terms of the $\ell^\infty$ norm intersected with the nonnegative orthant.

Comment: But that set is convex, isn't it? The box constraint on [0,1] coordinate-wise is convex, and the max_i x_i = 1 constraint is convex. The intersection of convex sets is convex.

Comment: No, the set defined by $\max_ix_i=1$ is *not* convex. Draw a picture in $\mathbb{R}^2$ if you don't believe me. Maybe you meant to write $\max_ix_i\leq 1$, which *is* convex.

Comment: Ah, crap.. I've made a dodo.. Back to the drawing board then. Any chance you have some thoughts on what kind of penalty would give me a good "spread" of the values in my parameter vector?

Answer (score 0):

Because $x_i \le 1$ for all $i$, one way to enforce $\max_i x_i = 1$ is to introduce binary variables $y_i$ and linear constraints
\begin{align}
\sum_i y_i &\ge 1 \tag1\label1\\
y_i &\le x_i &&\text{for all $i$} \tag2\label2
\end{align}
Constraint $\eqref{1}$ enforces $y_i = 1$ for at least one $i$.
Constraint $\eqref{2}$ enforces $y_i = 1 \implies x_i \ge 1$ (hence $x_i=1$).